# Question about the fundamental group of a connected, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open and connected. Suppose $f: I \to U$ is a loop with $a = f(0) = f(1)$ such that $f$ doesn't wind around any $p \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus U$.

a) Is it true that $f$ is nullhomotopic in $\pi_1(U, a)$?

b) Does $f$ represent the zero element in $H_1(U)$?

I suspect that the answer to a) is yes. I also think that implies b) is true as $H_1(U)$ is isomorphic to the abelianization of $\pi_1(U, a) = \pi_1(U)$ (As connected open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ implies path connected.)

My attempt at proving a) to be true relies on a few things I'm not certain about. 
Basically it assumes that $f$ can be homotoped to a differentiable function. So we can assume that, for $f(i) = (f_1(i), f_2(i))$ that $f_1', f_2'$ exist everywhere. Then we can cover the image of $f$ by an $\epsilon_1 > 0$ band that is still inside $U$. This comes from the fact that the image of $f$ is compact. Then the set of points that are inside the set bounded by the image of $f$ and $\epsilon_1 /2$ away from the image of $f$ is compact as well. So we repeat the process covering the entire set bounded by $Im(f)$ with these open bands that resemble $f$. By the compactness of that set we only need finitely many bands to cover. Then I think we can homotope $f$ to the constant loop by moving toward the interior of the loop in straight lines along $f'_1, f'_2$ for the first homotopy. Then we have another function for which those derivatives still exist and another band to move inside of. After finitely many steps we should be able to get a constant loop. This loop certainly won't take the value $a$ for any $i \in I$ but by path-connectedness the loop being constant is enough for it to be homotopic to the loop that is constantly $a$.

Here I'm assuming that the set bounded by $Im(f)$ is contained in $U$ which I believe follows from the winding assumption.

Does this seem reasonable? Is there a flaw in it? Am I not allowed to assume those derivatives exist? (I think that I should be able to smooth any cusps in the loop since I have an $\epsilon$ ball around any cusp point to work with. )

Am I right in thinking that a) $\implies$ b)?

Comment: What do you mean by «doesn't wind around any $p$», exactly?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Presumably OP means that the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of $f$ around each point $p\in \mathbb{R}^2-U$ is equal to zero.

Comment: (a) is true. I may well be wrong, but my impression is that it's not trivial; secure in the knowledge that someone will correct me if I'm wrong, I'm going to say I doubt that you can make an actual proof out of what you've written here. On the other hand (b) is false. At least it's false when $\mathbb R\setminus U$ contains two points $a\ne b$. You can find a picture of the counterexample in a lot of books on complex analysis: Sort of a figure eight - loops around $a$ first, then around $b$, then comes back and loops around $a$ in the opposite direction and then again around $b$...

Comment: @JimBelk, if that is the correct interpretation, then a commutator of two loops aroud different punctures (the example David describes, in fact) is a counterexample.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez That is an excellent point.  Although, based on OP's attempt to prove (a), it seems that $f$ is intended to be a simple closed curve.  But (a) is certainly false as stated.

Comment: A simple closed curve with zero winding number wrt any point in the complement contracts to a point thanks to the Schoenflies part of the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem

Comment: Aha, the thing that felt wrong about what I had written. You aren't guaranteed that the set bounded by the image of the loop is entirely contained in U.

Comment: I lied, they're both false. A person could describe the counterexample like so: Say $U$ is $\mathbb R$ with the two points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ removed. Consider the curve formed by joining the following sequence of points by straight lines: $(-2,1),(-2,-1),(2,1),(2,-1),(-2,-1),(-2,1),(2,-1),(2,1),(-2,1)$.

Comment: I should know better... I lied twice. (a) is false. (b) is true. (Anyone reading this: I wish people would shout when I say something dumb. Better for my own education to catch my own mistakes, but...)

Comment: So the aforementioned counterexample isn't a counterexample? Hmm, I need to think about this a lot. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Cros David C. Ullrich's example is a counterexample to (a) but not to (b).  Part (b) should be true in general.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to see that (b) is true? I'm just trying to convince myself that the loop in his example isn't nullhomotopic now. I'm not seeing a good way to show it but I'm going to think about it more tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

As Mariano Suárez-Alvarez pointed out in the comments, statement (a) is false in general, but true in the case of a simple closed curve.  For simple closed curves, it's essentially equivalent to the [Jordan-Schoenflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem), an "obvious" theorem of topology that's notoriously difficult to prove.

What's wrong with what you've written as a proof (even assuming $f$ is a simple closed curve) is that it only makes sense at all if you think of $f$ as having something like the shape of a circle.

To illustrate why (a) -- and by extension the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem -- is fairly hard to prove, consider the following curve:

[image]

The black curve is a simple closed curve, and has winding number zero around each of the red points.  If $U$ is the complement of the red points, can you prove that the black curve is nullhomotopic in $U$?

Comment: I think this is an unfair reason to think the Jordan curve theorem is hard to prove - in fact, it's incredibly easy to prove it for that particular curve, since it's piecewise linear. (The piecewise linear or smooth Jordan curve theorems have elementary and simple proofs.) I think more fair reasons are fractal-like curves: there are Jordan curves with [positive measure](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1903-004-01/S0002-9947-1903-1500628-5/home.html)! Why should something like that behave so well as to cut the plane into two pieces?

Comment: @MikeMiller Well, I agree that the case of a fractal curve is even harder, but the example I gave shows what's wrong with the OP's argument, which seemed to be assuming that a closed curve would always be shaped something like a circle.  Also, the full Jordan-Schoenflies theorem is relatively difficult even in the PL case, in the sense that it's probably harder than any proof that one sees in a first point-set topology course!

Comment: If the PL Schoenflies theorem is harder than anything covered in a first topology course, I have to wonder what's being covered in that first topology course! But I guess we'll have to agree to disagree.